# Time optimization. Why is the plot of a constant function so slow?

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning

If I run the following code

```
Timing[
 g[1, z_] := Coth[z];
 g[-1, z_] := Tanh[z];
 n = 1;
 k[b_, v_] := K /. {ToRules[
     N[Quiet@Reduce[K Cot[K (π/2 - 
               b/2)] == -Sqrt[2 v - K^2] g[(-1)^n, 
            Sqrt[2 v - K^2] (b/2)] && 
         0 < K < 4 Pi, K, 
        WorkingPrecision -> 5], {3, 3}]]};
 k[1, 2]
 ]
```

I get that It takes about 1 second to compute

```
{0.992794, {1.72, 3.26, 5.10, 7.10, 9.08, 11.1}}
```

but if I add a simple plot to my code It suddenly takes up to 150 seconds

```
Timing[
 g[1, z_] := Coth[z];
 g[-1, z_] := Tanh[z];
 n = 1;
 k[b_, v_] := K /. {ToRules[
     N[Quiet@Reduce[K Cot[K (π/2 - 
               b/2)] == -Sqrt[2 v - K^2] g[(-1)^n, 
            Sqrt[2 v - K^2] (b/2)] && 
         0 < K < 4 Pi, K, 
        WorkingPrecision -> 5], {3, 3}]]};
 Plot[k[1, 2],{x,-Pi/2,Pi/2}]
 ]
```

Notice that the only difference is the last row. Since k[1, 2] is a list of numbers how can it take so long time to compute if I put it into a plot? I also tried the following

```
Timing[
 g[1, z_] := Coth[z];
 g[-1, z_] := Tanh[z];
 n = 1;
 k[b_, v_] := K /. {ToRules[
     N[Quiet@Reduce[K Cot[K (π/2 - 
               b/2)] == -Sqrt[2 v - K^2] g[(-1)^n, 
            Sqrt[2 v - K^2] (b/2)] && 
         0 < K < 4 Pi, K, 
        WorkingPrecision -> 5], {3, 3}]]};
 e=k[1, 2];
 Plot[e,{x,-Pi/2,Pi/2}]
 ]
```

This time it just takes 1.2 seconds to compute. I don't what the big difference between putting k[1, 2] into the plot directly or setting k[1, 2] equal to a variable and then put that variable in to the plot.

Comment: But, what are you trying to do here? `k[1, 2]` is not a function of `x`.  Why are you trying to `Plot` it? `Plot` is probably trying to evaluate `k[1, 2]` multiple times at different `x` values, thinking that it's a function of `x`.

Comment: I'm just trying to plot a straight horisontal line between -pi/2 and pi/2.

Comment: Note that in the code you posted secondly, there is a `\[CapitalKappa]` instead of a `K`. Hence the equations cannot be reduced.

Comment: Moreover, using `NSolve` instead of `Reduce` makes things a lot quicker...

Comment: Yeah sorry \[CapitalKappa] should be K. I changed all my \[CapitalKappa]'s to K's when made this post. Also I'm trying to solve a transcendental equation so I don't think NSolve works.

Comment: `ListLinePlot[{{-Pi/2, k[1, 2]}, {Pi/2, k[1, 2]}}]`

Comment: Might be that `Plot` is reevaluating `k[1, 2]` at many sampling points, so could try `Plot[Evaluate[k[1, 2]], {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So the basic issue is that `k[1,2]` is a slowly evaluating function, combined with the fact that `Plot` tries to avoid fully evaluating functions before plugging in numbers (in order to be as faithfull as possible to the input).  So it repeatedly evaluates the whole RHS of the definition of `k` **for every single point in the range of `x`**.  If you change `Plot[k[1,2],{x,-1,1}]` to `Plot[Evaluate@k[1, 2], {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]`, you'll get a fast result, because then it evaluates `k[1,2]` once, before entering `Plot`, and plotting a constant array of numbers is easy.

Really, the strange issue is why is `Plot[e,{x,-Pi/2,Pi/2}]` fast? In the world of perfect linguistic consistency, it wouldn't be.  However, the idiom `f=x^2+2x; Plot[f,{x,-1,1}]` is so common that a special fast path was put in, which tests if the input is a symbol with a value which is a numeric expression in `x` (effectively using `Compile`).  So `e` is an expression which evaluates to a constant numeric expression (trivially a numeric expression in `x`), and so it is fast.  We therefore encounter a case where trying to be user friendly creates small inconsistencies in the language.  Whether that is good or bad is in the eye of the beholder.

Cute fact. If you would have foolish defined `e` using `SetDelayed` instead of `Set`, i.e. `e:=k[1,2]`, there would have been no speed up.  Why?  Because now the value of `e` would be the entire RHS of `k`, not the constant numeric list!  And since `Reduce` and `ReplaceAll` are not numerical functions, the test for 'numerical expression in `x`' would have failed.

**Addendum:** Nothing above is wrong, but I realized one point is slightly misleading.  Even without the special optimization, plotting `e` would have been relatively fast.  That's because `e` had already evaluated to constant numbers by virtue of writing `e=k[1,2]`.  So evaluating `e` at each point would take basically no time (contrast this with `e:=k[1,2]`), the penality would have been at most a few hundredths of a second.  So even without the special fast path for `Plot[e,...]`, the fact the `Set` had already fully evaluated the `k[1,2] would explain the speed up.  But there certainly could expressions where it made a difference.

Comment: Good answer. Very thorough!